# Zoom out in Xcode Storyboard Preview Mode with Keyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

While applying AutoLayout I have switched to Preview Mode On so Preview window is showing my design in iPhone 8,iPhone SE and iPad devices like this

[image]

now I want to zoom out so that no need to scroll Preview window Left and Right.

**Pinch Zoom In/Out is available in MacBooks** but i need it for mac mini

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Did you try right click on white area ?

Comment: @Nitis Right click is not working on Preview window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to double click in the white space area.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Double click is Working.